# How to use button to evaluate a cell

Tags: manipulate

I would like to create a button that when I click it it evaluates a cell containing a manipulate code. Also, I would like another button that when I click the output of manipulate disappears.

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 9):

The first button you don't have to create ;-) It's called the "Enter" button and it's already on your keyboard. Press it with the insertion cursor in the following block of code:

```
d = Manipulate[Plot[Sin[k x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}], {k, 1, 10}];
e = True;

Dynamic[If[e, d, ""]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The second button is generated below. Pressing it toggles the Manipulate between an on and off state.

```
Button["Manipulate On/Off", e = Not[e]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks, it works well in a notebook, but what about use it as a standalone cdf ? It appear doesn't work....

Comment: Nice, but it evaluates the `Manipulate` again when you turn it on, as opposed to simply making it disappear and reappear (like if you deleted the manipulate and immediately undid it).

Comment: R.M it is possible to paste the manipulate box in the Dynamic function (replacing the variable d). As far as I know there is no Visible->False option for a Manipulate; that would have been useful here. Another option would be to have the function in the Manipulate body to be replaced by a Null function depending on the button state.

Comment: @maxmc The [manual states about CDF's](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/howto/CreateAComputableDocumentFormatFile.html): "All interactive content must be generated with the Manipulate command and may only use mouse-driven elements, such as Slider, Locator, Checkbox, PopupMenu, etc." So, a button outside a Manipulate won't work in a CDF.